# How to define complex number power of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, matrix-calculus

Rational number or real number power of some $n*n$ matrix is able to be defined, can we define the complex number power of matrix like $S_{n\times n}^i $ $i$ is the complex number.

Comment: You could try to do this with the identity $a^b = \exp(b \ln a)$. The exponent and logarithm of a matrix are in general defined via series, when they converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the way to calculate this would be to utilize the natural logarithm of the matrix S;

$$S^i=e^{i\ln(S)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{i^n\over n!}\cdot ln^n(S)$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{i^n \cdot(-1)^n\over n!}\cdot\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(I-S)^k\over k}\right)^n$$

Comment: Although for some $S$ your logarithmic series wouldn't converge, forcing us to replace it with e.g. the series for $-\ln S^{-1}$, assuming _that_ converges.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for mentioning this. Forgot to mention the convergence issue for matrices "far away" from the identity...

Comment: It seems that the formula has some flaw, i power of a simplist matrix is not consistent to the result by this formula.